# Multiple MediaPlayers keep failing - Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android and Java development and am looking for some guidance in setting up a simple soundboard app. What I am trying to do and am having issues in getting it working effectively is handling events for multiple mediaplayers.

For example I am creating a soundboard whereby when I click a button I want all other sounds to be stopped and released from memory and the button I have just pressed to play its assigned sound. I realise that repeating code blocks is not a good programming approach, but I have tried this with arrays and switch statements too with little effect. Any guidance on how to effectively release sounds from memory when using multiple MediaPlayers would be very useful to me. I have included my code below for 4 buttons (I have over 30 on this app)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private MediaPlayer Meow1,Meow2,Meow3,Meow4;
private Button meowButton1,meowButton2,meowButton3,meowButton4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



 Meow1 = new MediaPlayer();
        Meow1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.meow1);
       // final Boolean Meow1Pause = !Meow1.isPlaying() && Meow1.getCurrentPosition() >1;
        meowButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Meow1);
        meowButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Meow1.isPlaying())
                { pauseMusic1();
                } else {
                    Meow1.start();
                }}
        });
        Meow1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer Meow1) {
                Meow1.stop();
                Meow1.reset();
                Meow1.release();

            }
        });



       Meow2 = new MediaPlayer();
       Meow2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.meow2);

        meowButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Meow2);
        meowButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Meow2.isPlaying() ){
                    pauseMusic();
                } else {
                    Meow2.start();      
        }}
        });

        Meow2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer Meow1) {
                Meow2.stop();
                Meow2.reset();
                Meow2.release();
            }
        });

        Meow3 = new MediaPlayer();
        Meow3 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.meow3);
        meowButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Meow3);
        meowButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Meow3.isPlaying())
                { pauseMusic();
                } else {
                    Meow3.start();
                }}
        });
        Meow3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer Meow1) {
                Meow3.stop();
                Meow3.reset();
                Meow3.release();

            }
        });

        Meow4 = new MediaPlayer();
        Meow4  = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.meow4);
        meowButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Meow4);
        meowButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Meow4.isPlaying())
                { pauseMusic();
                } else {
                    Meow4.start();
                }}
        });

}
public void pauseMusic()  {
    if(Meow1 != null && Meow1.isPlaying()) Meow1.pause();
    if(Meow2 != null && Meow2.isPlaying()) Meow2.pause();
    if(Meow3 != null && Meow3.isPlaying()) Meow3.pause();
    if(Meow4 != null && Meow4.isPlaying()) Meow4.pause();
}


}

Run Compiler:
A: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashScreen, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-6549553702477848745, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6549553702477848744}]
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 6376787
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x980fde60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3c3c290)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x980fde60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3c3c290)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x980fde60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3c3c290)
I/chatty: uid=10085(u0_a85) RenderThread identical 2 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x980fde60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3c3c290)
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
               cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
               cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
D/TAG1: Button 2 pressed
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: g.convery.cat_sounds, PID: 12276
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
                      at g.convery.cat_sounds.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:97)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
Application terminated.


LOGCAT:

05-31 09:21:30.099 12276-12288/g.convery.cat_sounds W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
05-31 09:21:30.211 12276-12288/g.convery.cat_sounds I/chatty: uid=10085(u0_a85) FinalizerDaemon identical 33 lines
05-31 09:21:30.212 12276-12288/g.convery.cat_sounds W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
05-31 09:21:30.283 12276-12284/g.convery.cat_sounds I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB
05-31 09:21:30.286 12276-12284/g.convery.cat_sounds I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=67KB
05-31 09:21:30.287 12276-12284/g.convery.cat_sounds I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
05-31 09:21:31.159 12276-12307/g.convery.cat_sounds I/chatty: uid=10085(u0_a85) RenderThread identical 2 lines
05-31 09:24:41.746 12276-12276/g.convery.cat_sounds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: g.convery.cat_sounds, PID: 12276
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
        at g.convery.cat_sounds.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
05-31 09:24:47.955 12276-12288/g.convery.cat_sounds W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
05-31 09:24:47.956 12276-12288/g.convery.cat_sounds W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the media player after releasing it. Remove these lines from your onCompletionListener and add them to onDestroy of your activity instead

```
Meow1.release();
Meow2.release();
Meow3.release();
Meow4.release();
```

Also calling create automatically creates a new instance, you can remove these lines as well

```
Meow1 = new MediaPlayer();
Meow2 = new MediaPlayer();
Meow3 = new MediaPlayer();
Meow4 = new MediaPlayer();
```

A better approach would be to use a single media player and just change the datesource when ever user wants to play different source, but this method will take some time before it plays the audio as it will prepare the audio everytime, this would be negligible unless your audio size is quite huge

Answer (score 0):

1. Look how you're controlling your media now:

   ```
   if (Meow4.isPlaying()) { 
       pauseMusic();
   } else {
       Meow4.start();
   }
   ```

   The first time you call `Meow4.isPlaying()` you will receive `IllegalStateException` because your player is not initialized.

   Look how your MediaPlayer state is defined and call appropriate function
2. The second point, when you encounter a duplicate block, you should think of a function.

   ```
   Meow3 = new MediaPlayer();
   Meow3 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.meow3);
   meowButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Meow3);
   meowButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   });
   meowButton3.setOnCompletionListener...
   ```

in a function: `registerPlayer(Context context, int resourceId, Button controlButton)`

```
Or with higher level of abstraction, create a subclass of `MediaPlayer` and wrap these logic inside it
```

3. Definitely you don't want to `Meow1.pause()` over and over. Instead, store your `MeoX` in a list then loop over it:

   ```
   List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();
   players.add(Meow1);
   ....
   public void pauseMusic()  {
        players.stream().filter(p -> p != null && p.isPlaying()).forEach(p -p.pause());
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Mate. I have abandoned the MediaPlayer class in favour of the SoundPool class which seems to be the best way to make a soundboard app. Thanks for your help, I will use this solution for my next app. I have opened up another post for some of the issues that I am now encountering with the SoundPool class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635392/android-studio-soundpool-not-playing-sounds-sporadically/50635450#50635450